# Is there a way to get the user/email for whom a shareable link is created for with MS Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm trying to get the email for what a shareable link works for (the info pointed in this image):

[image]

I was able to retrieve the permissions list for the drive item with the [List Permissions Endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-permissions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)
but it doesn't have that information.

Comment: Mapping product UI to APIs would be very helpful. This would be an interesting sort of new API documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [grantedToIdentities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/permission?view=graph-rest-beta) property is what I was looking for. It's only available on beta at the moment.

Comment: Thank you for the follow link to the answer!